# How can I find what dependencies is missing from a referenced dll?

Tags: c#, winforms

It's my own dll I created few years ago but I can't find yet the source.

The problem is what the exception mean and if there is a way to find what missing dependencies there are in the dll without it's source ?

The exception is in Program.cs on the line :

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

The exception happens once I'm running the application before it's executing any line of code in form1.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'unfreez_wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> HResult=0x8007007E
> Message=Could not load file or assembly 'unfreez_wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
> Source=Extract
> StackTrace:
> at Form1..ctor() in D:\Csharp Projects\Form1.cs:line 64
> at Program.Main() in D:\Csharp Projects\Program.cs:line 19

The form1 code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using unfreez_wrapper;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            List<string> times = new List<string>();
            UnFreezWrapper unfreez = new UnFreezWrapper();

            InitializeComponent();

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
            {
                client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36");
                client.DownloadFile("https://mytest.com/", @"D:\localfile.html");

                var file = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\localfile.html");

                int idx = file.IndexOf("arrayImageTimes.push");
                int idx1 = file.IndexOf("</script>", idx);

                string results = file.Substring(idx, idx1 - idx);

                var statements = results.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int i = 0; i < statements.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 10)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    string number = statements[i].Split('\'')[1];

                    times.Add(number); // add to a list instead

                    var link = "https://mytest.com" + number;
                    client.DownloadFile(link, @"D:\Images\Image" + i + ".gif");
                }

                List<string> myGifList = new List<string>();
                FileInfo[] fi;
                DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Images");
                fi = dir1.GetFiles(" *.gif");
                for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
                {
                    myGifList.Add(fi[i].FullName);
                }

                unfreez.MakeGIF(myGifList, @"D:\Images\agif", 100, true);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the unfreez_wrapper.dll in the solution and it's settings :

[image: unfreez_wrapper.dll]

Comment: You can open the assembly in ILDASM and double-click the MANIFEST node to see all the dependencies for that assembly.

Comment: [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases) would be another possibility.

Comment: DotPeek - I like

Comment: I would also look if you have any dependency redirects. May be it redirects you to a different version and it is not there